# Finding total number of combinations between flavors and toppings

Tags: ruby

I was taking a quiz in Ruby that required me to find the total number of unique combinations between flavors and toppings but I was stuck on a particular part. One of the rules was that "chocolate chip ice cream can't have chocolate chips toppings" or some wording similar to that. This wasn't the exact problem but I tried my best to create a similar problem. How would I go about solving this problem?

```
def combinations(flavors, toppings)
  
end


flavors = ["fudge", "vanilla", "chocolate chip", "cookie dough"] # 11
toppings = ["chocolate chips", "sprinkles", "mint"]
```

I first was thinking of doing a nested loop problem but that part that I was stuck on is that "chocolate chip" and "chocolate chips" isn't the same.

Comment: Hint: `flavors.map` and `toppings`.

Comment: Or `flavors.product`

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about using the map method to find the total number of combinations

Comment: @jvx8ss Has given you the [information you need](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/array#method-i-product).

Comment: `flavors.size * toppings.size - 1` ?

Comment: _"that ... and ... isn't the same"_ – well, another rule could disallow "mint" on "fudge". The textual similarity seems to be a coincidence. I would just create an array of forbidden flavor/topping combinations, e.g. `forbidden_combinations = [["chocolate chip", "chocolate chips"]]`. The remaining (allowed) combinations can then be calculated via `flavors.product(toppings) - forbidden_combinations`

Answer (score 1):

Consider an analogous situation. Use `#product` to find all combinations and then `#reject` to eliminate the ones that fail to meet the criteria.

In the below example, the second string cannot contain the first one. `#index` will return `nil` is the substring is not found.

```
x = ["a", "b", "c"]
y = ["as", "hello", "world"]

x.product(y).reject { |a, b| b.index(a) }
# => [["a", "hello"], ["a", "world"], ["b", "as"], 
#     ["b", "hello"], ["b", "world"], ["c", "as"], 
#     ["c", "hello"], ["c", "world"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give it away completely if it is a quiz question, but as always when solving programming problems, a good start is to break it down into smaller steps. I think the following should give you a good hint on how to do it.

1. Define what it means for two flavours to be the same. Is "chocolate chip" the same as "chocolate chips"? (note the 's' that is different) What about "chocolate" ice cream with "chocolate chips"? One way would be to say that two flavours are equal if one is a substring of the other. Another, slightly harder, way would be to say that they must be exactly the same, normalising away plural forms. Write yourself a function that can take two flavours and give you a `true`/`false` answer.

Hint: Check out the docs for the `#include?` method on `String` if you go with the first definition and remember that you might not know in advance which string is a substring of the other.

2. Build a list of all possible pairs when taking one element from each of the two arrays.

Hint: Check out the `#product` method on `Array` as mentioned by @jvx8ss.

3. Remove all pairs where both elements of the pair are equal according to the definition from step 1.

Hint: Check out the `#reject` method on `Array`.

All of the relevant docs can be found at https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856076/finding-total-number-of-combinations-between-flavors-and-toppings#answer-74857235) and considering not only that the first string should not be contained in the second, but also the other way around. I think it might be slightly better to [sort](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sort) the array first before doing the check with [reject](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reject).

```rb
def combinations(flavors, toppings)
  flavors.product(toppings).reject do |combo|
    first, second = combo.sort
    second.include?(first)
  end.count
end


flavors = ["fudge", "vanilla", "chocolate chip", "cookie dough"]
toppings = ["chocolate chips", "sprinkles", "mint"]

pp combinations(flavors, toppings) # => 11
```